# Обязательно ли у инфинитивного предложения должно быть модальное значение?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

"О чём больше всего мечтает выпускник? Работать в престижной международной компании и получать 250 тысяч".

В различных справочниках указано, что для инфинитивных предложений характерно модальное значение: необходимость, неизбежность, желательность и т.д. Здесь во втором предложении его нет, это просто ответ на предыдущий вопрос. Есть ли здесь ошибка в синтаксисе или в оформлении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Работать в престижной международной компании.

Это **неполное** предложение, полный вариант: **Он мечтает работать** в престижной международной компании.

Мечтает работать ― **составное глагольное сказуемое**, в котором могут использоваться два вида связок, **модальная и фазовая**: Он мечтает (хочет)работать. Он начал работать. Основное значение выражает глагол в форме инфинитива.

**Инфинитивное предложение** ― это немного другая тема. Эти предложения называются **безлично-инфинитивными.** Примеры: Мне не о чем мечтать. Мне есть о чем мечтать. О чём мне мечтать? К кому мне обратиться?

Comment: Ничего, что в первом предложении дополнение стоит в предложном падеже, а во втором дополнение — инфинитив?

Comment: Да, какая-то нестыковка есть. Как вариант: О чём больше всего мечтает выпускник? Он хочет работать в престижной международной компании и получать 250 тысяч.

Comment: А в неполном предложении не может подразумеваться "о том, чтобы"? Или это слишком неочевидно?

Comment: Здесь дело не только в грамматике, но и в семантике тоже. Вы что-то утверждаете, поэтому модальность тут ни к чему. Ведь уже обозначено, что в БОЛЬШИНСТВЕ случаев дело обстоит именно так: О чем он мечтает? Он хочет... Коротко, ясно, информативно.